# Simple Tailwind/CSS Animation Not Working

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, css-animations

I'm completely puzzled why a simple CSS transition isn't working. I have a hamburger menu that controls a state, and depending on the state I have a sidebar menu either appear or disappear. This works fine, but I want it to transition smoothly. Here's my code for reference:

```
"use client";
import { Spiral as Hamburger } from "hamburger-react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Nav() {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
      <div
        className={`top-0 right-0 w-[90vw] bg-pink-800 p-10 pl-20 text-white fixed h-full z-40 ease-in-out duration-300 ${
          isOpen ? "translate-x-0" : "translate-x-full"
        }`}
      >
        <h2 className="mt-20 text-4xl font-semibold text-white">
          I am a sidebar
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="md:hidden">
      <div className="absolute top-3 right-3 z-50">
        <Hamburger toggled={isOpen} toggle={setOpen} />
      </div>
      <Sidebar />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm using NextJS 13 and not sure if it's related to that, or if it's an issue with a Tailwind default style. I did notice when I check out the styles in the browser and I play around with removing a class (such as `--tw-scale-x: 1`) from the following list, the transition seems to work if my `isOpen` state is false (i.e., hamburger is closed).

```
*, ::before, ::after {
    --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
    --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
    --tw-translate-x: 0;
    --tw-translate-y: 0;
    --tw-rotate: 0;
    --tw-skew-x: 0;
    --tw-skew-y: 0;
    --tw-scale-x: 1;
    --tw-scale-y: 1;
    --tw-pan-x: ;
    --tw-pan-y: ;
    --tw-pinch-zoom: ;
    --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
    --tw-gradient-from-position: ;
    --tw-gradient-via-position: ;
    --tw-gradient-to-position: ;
    --tw-ordinal: ;
    --tw-slashed-zero: ;
    --tw-numeric-figure: ;
    --tw-numeric-spacing: ;
    --tw-numeric-fraction: ;
    --tw-ring-inset: ;
    --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
    --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
    --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
    --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
    --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
    --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
    --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
    --tw-blur: ;
    --tw-brightness: ;
    --tw-contrast: ;
    --tw-grayscale: ;
    --tw-hue-rotate: ;
    --tw-invert: ;
    --tw-saturate: ;
    --tw-sepia: ;
    --tw-drop-shadow: ;
    --tw-backdrop-blur: ;
    --tw-backdrop-brightness: ;
    --tw-backdrop-contrast: ;
    --tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;
    --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;
    --tw-backdrop-invert: ;
    --tw-backdrop-opacity: ;
    --tw-backdrop-saturate: ;
    --tw-backdrop-sepia: ;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I've tried using regular CSS to make the transition work, but to no avail.